# Category banner in a magento website

Tags: magento

I have moved the category banner into `2column.left.phtml`.

How can I do to display it on the category pages only and not on the product pages ?

For example my category page is "`cuff-links`" and when I click on a product on this category page the link changes to "`cufflinks/sliver-star`", from this point, I don't want to display the banner anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
$module = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$contoller = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
if($module == 'catalog' && $contoller == 'category') {

     // Catgeory Banner Content

}
```

Comment: i take it $module would be my category page and $ controller would be product page? Coz remember i want to hide the banner on product pages linked to cufflinks (category page),

Comment: As you only want to show banner on category page. you can add condition like this way. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Great. If it works .. please accept this as answer, so other get benefit too.